# Why the statement int null = 0, *p = null is illegal?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, nullptr

I'm new to C++ and am trying the learn the concept of pointer. Could someone tell me why the C++ statement below is illegal? It seems to me to be legit but I have been told its illegal.

```
int null = 0, *p = null;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ standard allows pointers to be assigned the value `0` as a constant.

However, the code:

```
int null = 0;
int *p = null;
```

does not set `p` to the constant `0`, it sets it to the value of `null`, which is an integer variable.

If we generalize a little bit, and put `int null = 0;` on a line, and `int *p = null;` in a completely different line, with some code in between. There is nothing saying that the code in between doesn't do `null = 4;` - however, I don't think that is the main reason for not allowing this, but rather that it is easier to write a compiler that checks "is this the integer constant 0" than "is this named constant of the value zero". What if the constant is from another compile unit (a link-time constant)?

Also, reading `0` is much easier than having 46 different coding standards, each of which uses a different name for `null`.

Note that even if you make `const int null = 0;`, it is still not the constant `0` - it's a constant of the same value as `0`, but not the same, lexically, as `0`.

Comment: Isn't the thread part a red herring? It's still illegal even if `null` is a `constexpr`.

Comment: @Cornstalks: I'm not entirely sure about the actual motivation, but clearly if the compiler DID allow the non-const variant, it would be a problem. And I was just adding about `const int null = 0;` when you wrote that comment.

Comment: Sure, I just think attempting to use threads as the justification is generally incorrect. The compiler can safely assume `null` is 0 in the statement `int *p = null;`. If a thread had interrupted execution and set `null` to something, it would be undefined behavior for the other thread to continue execution and read from `null` (a memory synchronization barrier would be required).

Comment: Ok, I've rewritten it a bit, such that it doesn't talk about interrupting by threads, but the more generic problem that if you have `int null = 0;`,. it's not guaranteed that `null = 4;` or some such happens later...

Answer (score 6):

If you try compiling this code then you should get the following error:

```
error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an lvalue of type 'int'
```

Essentially what is happening is that you are trying to initialize a pointer with a variable. The only thing that is allowed in C++ is assigning a pointer directly to a zero.

```
int * p = 0;
```

Something like the example above would work.

Answer (score 0):

To define a pointer you need to use ampersand sign (&) as a prefix to the object you are passing.

```
int null = 0, *p = &null;
```

That is going to fix `error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an value of type 'int'`

Comment: This 'fixes' the error, but changes the meaning of the code. It's like `x#y` produces an error, but `x+y` fixes it.

Comment: You obviously don't understand the intention of this line. It is suppose to define 2 integer types; first one with name null that holds value 0, and second integer that will take same value from the location of the first one, with the name p.

Comment: No, the second defines a pointer `p` initialized to the *value* of null, not to the *address* of `null`.

Comment: Keyword for defining null value in c++ is NULL or nullptr... not null. And # sign, im not sure it represents anything also.

Comment: There is no `NULL` keyword in C++. From C C++ inherited a [macro NULL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL), but all that is irrelevant here.

Comment: The obvious intention of the OP was to initialize the pointer `p` to `0`. Your modification instead initializes it to the address of `null`, something completely different.

Comment: No, the address of `null` does not have 0 value. You seem to fundamentally fail to understand what a pointer is.

Answer (score 0):

The example comes from an exercise in the textbook "C++ Primer, 5th edition"; and, while the quoted compiler error (`cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an value of type 'int'`) is actually the very simple answer to the OP's question I also suspect many of the people viewing this thread, like myself, are brought here in confusion from the textbook above.

The question comes after a section specifically on `constexpr` and it seems logical the desired answer would probably make use this newly described feature. I found four potential soultions but, as none of them made use of `constexpr`, I concluded I must have missed something.

After much time and constination I, eventially, realised the type could be unified in either direction: rather than setting p to an address, null could be initialised as a pointer:

```
// either
int *const null = 0;
// or
constexpr int *null = 0;
```

In either of the above cases, `int *p = null;` becomes a legal declaration.

This is, as far as I can tell, complelety redundent (my excuse for taking so long to realise), but does satisfy the criteria of making the code legal while also demonstrating how `constexpr` works with pointers.

I am only learning as well, so I may have missed something or made a mistake, but hope this may prove insightful to the next person confused by this section of the primer.

Incidentally, it may be of interest to note using the -fpermissive flag (with g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0 on WSL) generates a warning but compiles the original code just fine creating p with address 0.